# Why did the index of the summation change from $k\in F$ to $k=0$?

Tags: real-analysis

> **Proof**:
>
> Let $0\leq x\leq 1$ and note that $1\leq ((k/n)-x^2)/\delta^2$ for $k\in F$. Hence \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k\in F}{n\choose{k}}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}&\leq\frac{1}{\delta^2}\sum_{k\in F}\left(\frac{k}{n}-x\right)^2{n\choose k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}\\
> &\leq\frac{1}{\delta^2}\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{k}{n}-x\right)^2{n\choose k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}\\
> &\vdots\\
> &\text{ where }\delta>0,\\ &\text{ and } F \text{ denotes the set of } k \text { in } \{0,\ldots, n\},\\
> &\text{ for which } |(k/n)-x|\geq \delta 
> \end{align*}

The above is an excerpt from a proof in my textbook. After this, I understand the rest of the proof, but I am having trouble understanding how the author started.

I don't quite understand why we know that $k=0$ from $k\in F$ on the second line of the inequality.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume it is $\sum_{k=0}^n$ and not just $\sum_{k=0}$ (which makes littele sense)?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F$ is a subset of $\{0,1,\dots,n\}$, expressions are positive, hence sum over $\{0,1,\dots,n\}$ is (weakly) greater than over $F$.